# MAking API request always got "token_rejected" error

Tags: oauth, yahoo

I have developed a OAuth Component, and completed Yahoo's OAuth Process, got oauth_token.

But when I make API call to yahoo API (like contact or YQL), I always get "Token_Rejected" error message.

HTTP 401

Signature: `6fR3VdygGrRCO+WrS6tlD3hjHMI=`

base_string:

```
GET&http%3A%2F%2Fsocial.yahooapis.com%2Fv1%2Fuser%2FMOMJS2M2KSMQKT2D
Q4O7NS4JFU%2Fprofile%2Fusercard&oauth_consumer_key%3Ddj0yJmk9ZmZzUFVQblZzM1JVJmQ
9WVdrOU9GbFNRMUJuTmpRbWNHbzlOVFUyTWpRNU9EWXkmcz1jb25zdW1lcnNlY3JldCZ4PTJk%26oaut
h_nonce%3D2366072fe9829333b98eb6f2a7539afa%26oauth_signature_method%3DHMAC-SHA1%
26oauth_timestamp%3D1305099596%26oauth_token%3DA%3D4cnEo.njj1_C6XtkvR3o5x3vOYqrN
hHk3sBFh76pPtcKA07WF69OADx8zU7o0dPSRauN77UIBw.5bEk5opw15A8SSemxquErvhhHPuAhtm0SB
UuGBOSMxapwBdU1.E4oeQQMXIvKRFhy81EVbIDclBcxzeG.y.eEUdNFDkp_suVAKko.i6Tazpbfkqa1C
__7BAQO5m74CIsalgwyyI8z99eITPlzq_llb7CZzhoWJTVzVAVH_hoU2jBbjSwP00AGB.ovXqT0Ayf0.
WHG2v7hhFhVh.MEx6H0oa8rgpUSZr68dViiIPLfV6G.fGCF3GSnE4uVNiDWM2.x4Lf37slpGWqmjUTtX
B8UVlTQU0auc_YCbGC9wSiUHePWEhpzkgQ6lf.G0mZ9VJ5I_9jbZzlJD52ffUoMDVs97qEeT4CRRa.0p
hwt1dWx16pV.cmhRXSHUqCkDXVmCGpZI5rXD6fR2QoCoQNOOf6e3rGqaz1cF_kY4BgKfKWVa_RF.peOg
PIaUYF1L9CFtG2Zj1HkyhgzTcYbJZemoxO3WtOD8PHM3cUGJWvGcAibfDf1Ntu6BmsQa_aZfjZ11ou8n
F1kjeFsf9wUpHOvGS_qOtaUT8b5rV8CXd.mcZyLghscWIOy339QjgZ6nz2PVchf2P2Rd0JhbNR_OzHWb
5l9LBBOH9RM5TkHm7N2HSdxaSxSFA6rLU5gguZU7xFEnQ44o7hMCbyfL4SL6VdOz9hIuTjYh8GHHYTM0
iIU.O.Gh_tNPjLVZ8j6T2G2W1L5JgCYz8K_D7bn8EHL9FNwffqZQgmtXqjqpIFATcQ.h.91zP_uc4mij
gzvwnfE8n80N7hZKVA-%26oauth_version%3D1.0
```

Response:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<yahoo:error xmlns:yahoo='http://yahooapis.com/v1/base.rng'
xml:lang='en-US'>
<yahoo:description>Please provide valid credentials. OAuth oauth_problem="toke
n_rejected", realm="yahooapis.com"</yahoo:description>
</yahoo:error>
```

I am very sure this access token is not expired.

How to resolve this problem?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had resolved this question, the reason is I missed query string, when I encoded query string into base string, this issue had been solved.

Comment: @ina what is mean urlencode issues, i am getting the same error, how can i solve this error?

Comment: use proper url encoding

Answer (score 1):

For anyone coming across this question in the future:  If you keep getting "token rejected" from https://api.login.yahoo.com/oauth/v2/get_token using PHP.  Then make sure, if relevant to your flow, that you are calling urldecode on the access token prior to making this call.

Answer (score 0):

If you're storing the access token in a table, and then calling the API using the access token from that table, it will get shortened to 255 characters if you made the column a string.  I just changed it from a string to a text and stored it.

This is of course if you are storing the access token in a table and then making the call.  I had this exact same error message, once I fixed that it worked.

Hope I could help,

Goran

Comment: The access token is used directly to call API, not stored and query from database, my database column is varchar(8000), so it's enough to store access token value.